# How do I use angular directive as an alternative to ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I would like to know how I would be able to use a directive to display a list of items instead of using angular's ng-repeat. I intend to do this because I am using the Semantic Ui framework which unfortunately fails to display my ng-repeat secondary dropdown menu.

Assuming I have an object named topics:

```
var topics = [{id: 1, title: "one"}, {id: 2, title: "two"}, {id: 3, title: "three"}];
```

then how can I use a directive to display topics in a list as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

The end result needs be as follows:

- one
- two
- three

I am asking this because I am new to directives in angular. This is just a simplified problem to the bigger problem that I intend to solve the complex problem that I have.

Comment: The question is too broad. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - Creating Custom Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Then edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [*X/Y Problem*](http://xyproblem.info/). I think you should analyse why Semantic UI fails to display your menu

Comment: FYI, `ng-repeat` is just another directive, the source code of which is readily available